# Classifying the solutions of the function $f(x)= \frac{1}{2}f(x-1)+\frac{1}{2}f(x+1)$

Tags: functions, recursion

I found this question on a GRE practice exam. It is stated as follows.

Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined on the set of integers and satisfying $f(x)= \frac{1}{2}f(x-1)+\frac{1}{2}f(x+1)$. Which of the following must be true?

I. The graph of $f$ is a subset of a line.

II. $f$ is strictly increasing.

III. $f$ is a constant function.

My approach was to plot points on a graph. First I choose 2 arbitrary points for $f(x-1)$ and $f(x+1)$. Then, $f(x)$ is the midpoint between $f(x-1)$ and $f(x+1)$ while $x$ is the midpoint between $x-1$ and $x+1$. These three points lie on a line which led me to believe that I. is true. If I choose $f(x-1)$ to be greater than $f(x+1)$, then the three points will be a subset of a line with negative slope, which would rule out II. and III.. Since what I've done isn't very rigorous, I am wondering if my reasoning is correct or if there is an easier/faster way to look at this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you heard of recurrence relations before?

Comment: Note that whereas some work remains to be done to rigorously prove the positive result that I. holds, you've basically done all the work to prove the negative result that II. and III. don't hold -- just substitute a function describing a line with negative slope, e.g. $f(x)=-x$, into the given functional equation and verify that it's fulfilled, thereby disproving II. and III. by a counterexample.

Comment: @Cataline Yes I have heard of them but haven't dealt with many of them besides a select few.

Comment: @joriki Thanks for the help and confirmation. It seems as though many of the questions on the GRE are made nearly impossible to solve rigorously in a short amount of time, but seem simple if you can step back and use a little intuition and/or clever thinking. I suppose it is pretty easy to fall into those traps they set up if you aren't on your toes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I look at it: after some rearrangement you have that
$$f(x+1) - f(x) = f(x) - f(x-1)$$
Or $\Delta {f}_{x+1} = \Delta f_x$ where $\Delta f_i$ is the change in $f$ between $i-1$ and $i$. Since the function is increasing by the same amount every step, it must be a subset of a line.

Comment: This is very simple to understand and helpful. Thanks.